# I'm inquiring about streamlet errors

Tags: streamlit

ModuleNotFoundError: This app has encountered an error. The original error message is redacted to prevent data leaks. Full error details have been recorded in the logs (if you're on Streamlit Cloud, click on 'Manage app' in the lower right of your app).
Traceback:
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 534, in _run_script
exec(code, module.**dict**)
File "/mount/src/ai-tutor-project/main.py", line 2, in 
import googletrans

I kept trying, but it's hard to find errors, so I'm inquiring. Please help me.

I kept trying, but it's hard to find errors, so I'm inquiring. Please help me.

Comment: Please share a runnable code snippet so we can reproduce the error

Comment: import streamlit as st
import googletrans
from langchain.llms import CTransformers
from streamlit.scriptrunner import add_script_run_ctx

translator = googletrans.Translator()

llm = CTransformers(
    model="llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q2_K (2).bin",
    model_type="llama"
)

st.title('AI tutor')

Comment: content = st.text_input("답변을 요청하세요!")

if st.button('요청하기'):
    with st.spinner('잠시만 기다려주세요...'):
        content_en = translator.translate(content, dest="en", src='auto').text
        result = llm.predict("Explain about" + content_en + " to elementary school students easily:")
        translation = translator.translate(result, src='en', dest='ko').text  # 영어에서 한국어로 번역
        st.write(translation)  # 번역된 결과 출력

Comment: Please add it to your original post and format it as code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77568360/streamlit-deployment-not-possible-please-help-me